# How to read the file and save into the hashmap, then save the first element as the key and the rest in a set?

Tags: java

I am reading a file with a disease name and its remedies. Therefore, i want to save the name as key and remedies in a set as the value. How can i reach that? It seems there is some problems in my code.

```
public static HashMap<String,Set<String>> disease = new HashMap <> ();

public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner fin = null;
    try {

        fin = new Scanner (new File ("diseases.txt"));
        while (fin.hasNextLine()) {
            HashSet <String> remedies = null;
            String [] parts = fin.nextLine().split(",");            
            int i = 1;
            while (fin.hasNext()) {
                remedies.add(parts[i].trim());
                i++;
            }

            disease.put(parts[0],remedies);


        }
        fin.close();
        }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        try {fin.close();} catch(Exception e) {}
    }
    Set <String> result = disease.get("thrombosis");
    display(result);

    public static <T> void display (Set<T> items) {
    if (items == null)
        return;
    int LEN = 80;
    String line = "[";
    for (T item:items) {
        line+= item.toString() + ",";
        if (line.length()> LEN) {
            line = "";
        }
    }
    System.out.println(line + "]");
}
```

here is my code

cancer,pain,swelling,bleeding,weight loss

gout,pain,swelling
hepatitis A,discoloration,malaise,tiredness

thrombosis,high heart rate

diabetes,frequent urination

and here is what the txt contains.

Comment: `while (fin.hasNext()) {
                remedies.add(parts[i].trim());
                i++;
            }` after reading a line you are still reading with your file pointer you shouldn't do that, instead do `for (int i=1; i< parts.length; i++) { remedies.add(parts[i].trim()); }` and file description is disease and symptoms not disease and remedies

Comment: I tried that but what print out is still blank.

Answer (score 1):

In your code , you haven't initialized the remedies HashSet(thats why it is throwing NullPointerException at line number 14). 
and second issue is : i is getting incremented by 1 and you are not checking with size of your pats array ( i > parts.length) . 
I edited your code :

```
    Scanner fin = null;
    try {

        fin = new Scanner(new File("diseases.txt"));
        while (fin.hasNextLine()) {
              HashSet<String> remedies = new HashSet<String>();
            String[] parts = fin.nextLine().split(",");
            int i = 1;
            while (fin.hasNext()&&parts.length>i) {
                remedies.add(parts[i].trim());
                i++;
            }

            disease.put(parts[0], remedies);


        }
```

Comment: It can be printed out but the result was wrong. What there should be is high heart rate, but i got the swelling and malaise

Comment: remedies should be initialized inside the while loop . replace with this code

 while (fin.hasNextLine()) {
                HashSet<String> remedies = new HashSet<String>();
                String[] parts = fin.nextLine().split(",");
                int i = 1;
                while (fin.hasNext()&&parts.length>i) {
                    remedies.add(parts[i].trim());
                    i++;
                }

                disease.put(parts[0], remedies);


            }

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Set;

public class Solution {

    public static HashMap<String, Set<String>> disease = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner fin = null;
        try {

            fin = new Scanner (new File("diseases.txt"));
            while (fin.hasNextLine()) {
                HashSet <String> remedies = new HashSet<>();
                String [] parts = fin.nextLine().split(",");            
                for (int i=1; i < parts.length; i++) {
                    remedies.add(parts[i].trim());
                }
                disease.put(parts[0],remedies);
            }
            fin.close();
            }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            try {fin.close();} catch(Exception e) {}
        }
        Set <String> result = disease.get("thrombosis");
        display(result);
    }

    public static <T> void display(Set<T> items) {
        if (items == null)
            return;
        int LEN = 80;
        String line = "[";
        for (T item : items) {
            line += item.toString() + ",";
            if (line.length() > LEN) {
                line = "";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(line + "]");
    }

}
```

Here is full working code. As suggested by @Pratik that you forget to initialize HashSet that's why NullPointerException error was coming.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues here:

1. no need for inner while loop (`while (fin.hasNext()) {`) - instead use `for(int i=1; i

   `HashSet <String> remedies = null;` - this means the set is not initialized and we cannot put items in it - nede to change to: `HashSet<String> remedies = new HashSet<>();`

   It is better practice to `close()` the file in the `finally` part

   The 'display' method will delete the line (if it is longer than 80 characters) before printing it.

   it is better to use StringBuilder when appending strings

So the corrected code would be:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class TestSOCode {
    public static HashMap<String,Set<String>> disease = new HashMap<>();
    private static int LINE_LENGTH = 80;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner fin = null;
        try {

            fin = new Scanner(new File("diseases.txt"));
            while (fin.hasNextLine()) {
                HashSet<String> remedies = new HashSet<>();
                String[] parts = fin.nextLine().split(",");

                disease.put(parts[0], remedies);

                for (int i = 1; i < parts.length; i++) {
                    remedies.add(parts[i].trim());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                fin.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error when closing file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        Set<String> result = disease.get("thrombosis");
        display(result);
    }

    public static <T> void display (Set<T> items) {
        if (items == null)
            return;

        StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder("[");
        int currentLength = 1; // start from 1 because of the '[' char
        for (T item:items) {
            String itemStr = item.toString();
            line.append(itemStr).append(",");
            currentLength += itemStr.length() + 1; // itemStr length plus the ',' char
            if (currentLength >= LINE_LENGTH) {
                line.append("\n");
                currentLength = 0;
            }
        }

        // replace last ',' with ']'
        line.replace(line.length() - 1, line.length(), "]");


        System.out.println(line.toString());
    }
}
```